Pandas: isin() doesn't produce the same result when the list it takes hold elements in different orders
I am trying to filter columns with data types including 'object', 'datetime64[ns]', and 'int64'. I get different results when the data type list is in different orders.
Specifically, when I run train.dtypes.isin(['object', 'datetime64[ns]', 'int64']), I get customer_ID is in the data type list,
but when I run train.dtypes.isin(['datetime64[ns]', 'int64', 'object']), I get customer_ID is not in the data type list.
customer_ID has the 'object' type when I run train.dtypes so I expect these two lines give the same result but in fact they don't. Why does the order matters? Does this have anything to do with how pandas compare data types and how isin() handles multiple comparison?
I have tried using explicit OR operand | instead of using isin(): train.dtypes[(train.dtypes == 'datetime64[ns]') | (train.dtypes == 'int64') | (train.dtypes == 'object')]. This returns the result I expect. But still I wonder why isin() does not work as expected.

I could not reproduce it. Are you certain you did not have a typo in 'object' in the second in your code and/or that customer_ID is actually an object in the second one (and not, say, something converted to a float64)?

Try train.dtypes.astype(str).isin(...).

Please post a [mre]

I don't have an answer, but can share some findings:
Firstly, reproducible example:
import pandas as pd

t = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 1, '01-01-2000']
], columns=['o', 'i', 'd'])
t['d'] = pd.to_datetime(t.d)

print(t.dtypes.isin(['object', 'datetime64[ns]', 'int64']).tolist())
print(t.dtypes.isin(['datetime64[ns]', 'int64', 'object']).tolist())
# [False, True, False]
# [True, True, False]

dtypes of t are:
o            object
i             int64
d    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object 

Or, another way
print(t.dtypes.tolist())
# dtype('O'), dtype('int64'), dtype('<M8[ns]')

Secondly, I dive a little into pandas code, and can say that problem is in this function: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.2.2/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L545
and its results are really strange and hard to explain:
from pandas.core import algorithms
from pandas._libs import hashtable

values = np.array(['object', 'datetime64[ns]', 'int64', 'qwerty', '<M8[ns]'], dtype=object)
for ind in [[0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 2], 
            [0, 2], [2, 0], [2, 0, 2], [0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 3], 
            [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3, 1], [0, 4, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3, 4],
            [0], [1], [2]]:
    value = values[ind]
    print(value, ":", hashtable.ismember(t.dtypes.values, value))
#  ['object' 'datetime64[ns]' 'int64'] : [False  True False]
#  ['int64' 'datetime64[ns]' 'object'] : [ True  True False]
#  ['datetime64[ns]' 'int64' 'object'] : [ True  True False]
#  ['datetime64[ns]' 'object' 'int64'] : [False  True False]
#  ['object' 'int64'] : [False False False]
#  ['int64' 'object'] : [False  True False]
#  ['int64' 'object' 'int64'] : [False  True False]
#  ['object' 'int64' 'int64'] : [False False False]
#  ['object' 'int64' 'qwerty'] : [False  True False]
#  ['object' 'datetime64[ns]' 'int64' 'qwerty'] : [False False False]
#  ['object' 'int64' 'qwerty' 'datetime64[ns]'] : [False False False]
#  ['object' '<M8[ns]' 'int64' 'qwerty'] : [False False False]
#  ['object' 'int64' 'qwerty' '<M8[ns]'] : [False False  True]
#  ['object'] : [False False False]
#  ['datetime64[ns]'] : [False False False]
#  ['int64'] : [False False False]

For 'normal' arrays it works as expected:
hashtable.ismember(
    np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=object), 
    np.array([3.0, 2.0, 1.0], dtype=object)
)
# True, True, True, False

But this is dead end for me.
In this function code I couldn't find any hints, why magic occurs.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.2.2/pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi.in#L210
Probably problem is in hashing of the object type algorithm, but I cannot find it's realization.
